# How can I get particular field value?

Tags: html, checkbox, html-table

I have one table, in this table two columns and 5 rows are there. In First column have a check box and second column have a data. I want get the second column row value of checked items. 
My table id was "tb1", checkbox id "cb1" and second field id "da1".

[image]

I want the result like "Data2 and Data5" That means whatever I check, that particular second column(`<td>`) value.

This is possible, please help me.

Comment: What do you mean by "get"? In what language? On the client or on a server?

Comment: Are the rows added dynamically or manually?

Comment: provide some more info to help you, meanwhile, what u have tried so far, add that too in your question to make everyone clear.

Comment: rows are added dynamically

Comment: You always want to get no 2 & 5 regardless of the number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

**[JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/vawagubu/2/edit)**

Bind the event on every `checkbox` and the find **second field"** with the help of `closest`

**JavaScript**

```
   $(function(){
  $("#tb1").on('click','input',function(){
      var value =($(this).closest('tr').find('[id^=da]').text())
    alert(value)
  })
})
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="tb1" cellpadding="5" border="1" cellspacing='0' width="200"> 
  <tr>
    <td id="cb1"><input type='checkbox' /> </td>
    <td id="da1">Data 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cb2"><input type='checkbox' /> </td>
    <td id="da2">Data 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cb3"><input type='checkbox' /> </td>
    <td id="da3">Data 3</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="cb4"><input type='checkbox' /> </td>
    <td id="da4">Data 4</td>
  </tr>


</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using cb2 and da2 for row two, then in javascript you could do:

If data column is td element only:

```
document.getElementById("da2").innerText
```

If data column is input element:

```
document.getElementById("da2").value;
```